# Aave & de bank.com

Tags: solidity

Debank.com shows my wallet, Aave, &
Uniswap assets, $1740, however, I can't locate the assets on these sites. My metamask wallet is connected. I don't recall getting a etoken and I just want them return to my metamask wallet so I can
cash out. There's no withdrawal option or unstake..maybe I didn't have the right amt to stake & the crypto just been sitting there......
Could anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Additional details such as specific assets involved, recent transactions, any recent activities on Debank.com, Aave, or Uniswap, and any error messages or notifications encountered would help in understanding and addressing the issue more effectively.